# How to use jBPM5 with Tomcat to develop web project?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jboss, jbpm

I am new to jBPM5, and I have no idea to develop a web project with jBPM5. Could anybody give me some instructions? I need help to start. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use jBPM as a library embeded in your project or separately as a server (even using the default jboss setup along with tomcat) with ready implementations and call its REST API from your web app. You can use it without persistence in memory or fully persistent with a database.

Inside the jbpm eclipse ide you can create bpmn2 diagrams and implement code using the jBPM API running localy. Afterwards you can include them in your web project's war and deploy them as part of you web project or deploy the bpmn2 resources on Guvnor repository and use them from your web app. The latter approach allows you to dynamically modify your process diagrams without restarting your application.

Have a look at the documentation it is pretty extensive
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.4/userguide/

Also look at the community forum you will find many usefule links.
https://community.jboss.org/thread/166771
a little old but will get you started